# Restrict subdomain to root access

Tags: php, dns, web, subdomain, restrict

is It possible to restrict a subdomain from accessing its parent domain? For example
I have a domain called example.com which files are in /public_html
then I have a subdomain, `name.example.com`, which is located in `/public_html/name`. Now I want to prevent the files in the subdomain from accessing the files in the parent domain in every way. So , that includes, JavaScript and PHP, but PHP is allowed on both the subdomain and parent domain
any solutions for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your apache **httpd.conf** file, please see [Security Tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles)

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

This will forbid default access to filesystem locations. Add appropriate Directory blocks to allow access only in those areas you wish. For example,

```
<Directory /usr/users/*/public_html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/local/httpd>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank You , for the information, i am guessing it'll work, but sadly I can't use this solution. I talked to the staff of my hosting provider, and , as I expected actually, they don't allow you to change the config file